Testing a [sometimes] empty React component with testing-library
I have a React component that renders a series of buttons -- unless the user has turned off the setting, in which case it returns an empty component (<></>). I'm having trouble writing tests for the the "it should be empty" case (using testing-library / testing-library/react).
I can easily test the case where buttons are supposed to appear, since the testing library find* methods wait until the elements are in the doc:
render(<MyComponent showButtons />);

const btns = await screen.findAllByRole('button');
assert.strictEqual(btns.length, 5);

However, I'm having trouble testing the case where there should be no buttons, because I'm having trouble figuring out when the component has finished loading; there are some async calls that happen in the background, before it decides that yes, it should be returning an empty component. The only option I could think of is this hack:
const renderResult = render(<MyComponent showButtons={false} />);

// this is the hack
await userEvent.click(renderResult.baseElement, { delay: 100 });
const btns = screen.queryAllByRole('button');
assert.strictEqual(btns.length, 0);

Without waiting for that click event (specifically, the delay on that event), the tests hang until a timeout occurs.
Is there a better way that I can tell the component has finished loading---the background processes are all done, any renders and re-renders are all complete---even though it's empty?

I should mention that I saw another thread in which someone mentioned using act, since it will wait for any useEffect hooks to complete; something similar to await act(async () => {}); -- but in my case, the component in question doesn't use useEffect, and trying this left me with the same hanging/timeout issue.

Maybe it should have occurred to me earlier, but I found a slightly more elegant solution than by clicking the body (with a delay): if I wrap the component in a div with some text, I can wait for the text:
const renderResult = render(
  <div>
    <div>MYTEXT</div>
    <div>
      <MyComponent showButtons={false} />
    </div>
  </div>
);

await screen.findByText('MYTEXT');
const btns = screen.queryAllByRole('button');
assert.strictEqual(btns.length, 0);

